# Komodo Edit autocompletion JS object literal

Tags: javascript, oop, komodo, jsdoc, code-intelligence

The problem is Komodo intelli-sense  doesn't see object methods defined this way:

```
var App = window.App || {
  method: function() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Typing "App." gives no result.

However, defining an object like below works fine:

```
var App = {
   method: function(){
   }
}
```

How to make autocompletion working at first example pattern?

Comment: So if your (implied) question is how to work around this I guess you could omit the `window.App||` part while you are editing the file and then put it back for testing/deployment.

Comment: Yep, but I wish intelli-sense were more intelligent :)

Answer (score 2):

Komodo has a [macro API](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.1/macroapi.html) which can automate switching between the two patterns. Use the [Add macro](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.1/macros.html#macros_writing) context menu option to create a new macro and paste the following code:

```
komodo.assertMacroVersion(2);
if (komodo.view && komodo.view.scintilla) { komodo.view.scintilla.focus(); } // bug 67103

// define visual mode pattern
var logical_or = RegExp(/\swindow.App\s\|\|/).exec(ko.views.manager.currentView.scimoz.text);

// check for visual mode pattern 
if (logical_or)
  {
  Find_ReplaceAllInMacro(window, 0, '\\s(window.App\\s\\|\\|)', '/*\\1*/', true, 2, 0, false, false);  // replace with intellisense mode pattern
  // show mode in status bar
  ko.statusBar.AddMessage("Intellisense Mode", "imap", 0); 
  }
// check for intellisense mode pattern
else
  {
  Find_ReplaceAllInMacro(window, 0, '/*window.App ||*/', ' window.App ||', true, 0, 0, false, false);
  ko.statusBar.AddMessage("Visual Mode", "vmap", 0);
  }
```

Click the macro in the toolbox to toggle between intellisense mode and visual mode.

As an alternative, a [JSDoc comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10948716/1113772) may work as well.