# How to make WebStorm resolve modules which are functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, jsdoc, commonjs

WebStorm does a very good job of resolving functions which are returned from CommonJS modules as methods (and reads JsDoc associated with them), like for instance:

```
// utils/valid.js
/**
 * Returns true no matter what.
 * @param {HTMLElement} element
 * @return {boolean}
 */
function isValid(element) {
    return true;
}
module.exports.isValid = isValid; // exports property
```

Such a function is then correctly provided in [code completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/basic-code-completion-completing-names-and-keywords.html) and [inline documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/viewing-inline-documentation.html) mechanisms when such a module is required in another file.

```
// main.js
var isValid = require('./utils/isValid').isValid; // works well
```

However, this fails when the function is returned directly as module exports

```
// utils/valid.js
module.exports = isValid; // exports object is a function
```

So when such a module is required, WebStorm seems to not know what it is:

```
// main.js
var isValid = require('./utils/isValid'); // doesn't work
```

This is very common in our project and changing all `module.exports` to plain objects is not an option. Is there any way for fix this issue in WebStorm?

Comment: how do you use it? Please provide the complete sample

Comment: I added a few more lines in the samples, however how I actually use the module is not related to the issue - the main point is that eg. pressing Ctrl+Q should display inline documentation for the module regardless of the way which was used to define it https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/viewing-inline-documentation.html

Comment: I agree with Paul S, how he uses it isn't related to the issue. I too am having this problem, did you get any further with it Paul?

Comment: Unfortunately not. However, my opinion on this is that although the above is technically correct, it's architecturally defective. The split of modules is too fine-grained, but also regardless of granularity it's better to stick to the convention of returning a plain object with methods (even if it's just a single method).

Answer (score 0):

Create a macro to switch between the two semantic forms:

```html
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/J3YX1WIScAk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**References**

- [Using Macros in the Editor - Help | WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html)
- [Komodo Edit autocompletion JS object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392676/)